# ScheduledExecutorService only calling one thread

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I want to pull multiple files from a queue and parse them simultaneously.  However, my executor is only calling one thread:

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService parsingExec ;
protected static BlockingQueue<Path> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
int threadPoolSize = 10;
parsingExec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
parsingExec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyParser(queue), 0, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: You only have one job scheduled in the code you are showing. Why are you expecting different behaviour?

Comment: I copied the wrong method. I corrected the code to call parsingExec.scheduleAtFixedRate().  Shouldn't this call multiple MyParser() instances?

Comment: It's hard to imagine that calling that method with 0,0 is legal, does that really not throw an exception?

Comment: It should throw IllegalArgumentException when Period is less or equal to zero. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @TedPrz where do you use `discoveryExec`?

Comment: @Fildor should have been parsingExec ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Javadoc for `scheduleWithFixedRate()`:

> Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period;
>   that is executions will commence after initialDelay then
>   initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on. If any
>   execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions
>   are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via
>   cancellation or termination of the executor. If any execution of this
>   task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may
>   start late, but will not concurrently execute.

This method is for scheduling a single task, to be executed multiple times. The key thing to note being that *only one* instance of your task will ever be executing at a time. If you want to execute multiple tasks simultaneously then you should be using, for example, a fixed thread pool instead.

```
final ExecutorService parsingExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
for(final int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
    parsingExec.submit(new MyParser(queue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parsingExec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyParser(queue), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This line schedules one Runnable. You have to call this line once for every Thread you want do schedule simultaniusly. I think you should split up the `queue` and give the splitted parts to your Constructor, and schedule them once for every part. Also `scheduleAtFixedRate` repeates the job forever, I think you don't want this behavior.
If you want to execute this just once use `submit` instead:

```
//split the queue in parts before
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfQueueParts; i++) {
    parsingExec.submit(new MyParser(queuePart));
}
```